# How to store multiple objects in NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Im storing a NSmutableArray in a NSUSerdefaults and in the Array I want to store multiple strings from a Textfield, but when I read the number of objects in NSlog it sends only the last object that I write... Heres my code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *tasks;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];

    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count); <--- If i write more than 2 strings it sends only the last one and 1 number of task.
}
```

So hope you help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

With:

```
if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Your original way is creating a new array, that means that anything previously stored in self.tasks is overwritten and doesn't exist. When you then set the NSUserDefaults "tasks" value to this array, it replaces the old one with this newly allocated one, which doesn't contain previously stored items.

By using if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new]; we only create a new array if one doesn't already exist:

Please note that on initial future instantiations, using a new NSMutableArray probably isn't wise and you should do something like this, based on Wain's answer:

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithDictionary:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
```

This way when you first initialize self.tasks it is synced with your userDefault value

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your array, but never reading it back. So, each time you replace the existing data instead of appending to it. Try:

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithDictionary:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing exactly what you've asked for.  Are you wanting to build up this array of strings over time?  If so, you'll need to do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *tasks = nil;
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tasks"]) {
   tasks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tasks"]];
} else {
   tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
}

// Add new task
[tasks addObject: [textField text] ];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Note: I'm not using Xcode right now, so treat the above as pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *strings = [@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"] mutableCopy];

[preferences setObject:strings forKey:@"strings"];

NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [preferences objectForKey:@"strings"];

for (NSString *string in stringsArray) {
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
}
```

As you would expect, I got 3 log messages, one for each `NSString`.

Can you show the output of your `NSLog` calls?

As mentioned by other answers, the specific code you posted is over-writing the stored `NSMutableArray` every time, such that you'll only ever get the single (last) item you pushed. You should check for `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` already having an `objectForKey` before creating a brand new `NSMutableArray` and using it for assignment.

Something like this should work:

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *tasks = [preferences objectForKey:@"tasks"];
if (tasks == nil) {
    tasks = [NSMutableArray array];
}

id task = nil; // create the new task somehow

[tasks addObject:task];

[preferences setObject:tasks forKey:@"tasks"];

for (id task in [preferences objectForKey:@"tasks"]) {
    // you should now have an array that is being built incrementally
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if(!self.tasks)
        self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];

    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count);
}
```